# Reopen a truncated file while following a file with less

Tags: log-files, less

Sometimes I am running a `less +F` on a log file, which I then truncate. I would like `less` to realize that the file has been truncated and start following the file as it is now. Currently, I am forced to do the following:

1. (terminal 1) > `less +F my-file.txt`
2. (terminal 2) > `printf "" > my-file.txt`
3. (terminal 1) > quit less
4. (terminal 1) > restart less: `less +F my-file.txt`

And I have to do steps 3-4 **every time** that I truncate the file (which is *dozens* o times a day). This is really a pain.

I would like to do:

1. (terminal 1) > `less +F my-file.txt` (and whatever extra option is needed)
2. (terminal 2) > `printf "" > my-file.txt`

And that's it. `less` would be automatically aware that the file has been truncated, and start following the new file from the beginning.

Is this possible? What flag should I use for less to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Not precisely the answer you were looking for, but you could try using '**tail -F**' (As opposed to '**tail -f**') which will give you exactly the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but tail is very limited compared to less. I want to use less, but I also want this tail feature.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you combine them like so?

`tail -F filename | tee | less`

This works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify the `--follow-name` argument to `less`. From [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less):

> Normally, if the input file is renamed while an F command is
>   executing, less will continue to display the contents of the original
>   file despite its name change. If --follow-name is specified, during an
>   F command less will periodically attempt to reopen the file by name.
>   If the reopen succeeds and the file is a different file from the
>   original (which means that a new file has been created with the same
>   name as the original (now renamed) file), less will display the
>   contents of that new file.

So your steps would now be:

1. (terminal 1) > `less --follow-name +F my-file.txt`
2. (terminal 2) > `printf "" > my-file.txt`
3. (terminal 1) > enjoy!

P.S. Instead of using printf, lots of shells will truncate with just the redirection operator: `> my-file.txt`